# python os.listdir() not displaying all of the files on my desktop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running windows 7 and using the idle interpreter. os.listdir() is not displaying all of the files on my desktop. This is the output I get when I run the command from idle:

```
    >>> os.listdir('C:\\Users\\Desktop') 
   ['CodeBlocks.lnk', 'Daily to Do - Shortcut.lnk', 'desktop.ini', 'DeSmuME', 
   'Google Chrome.lnk', 'idle.py', 'MilkShape 3D 1.8.4.lnk', 'Notepad++.lnk', 
   'PCSX2 1.2.1', 'ScpDriver - Shortcut.lnk', 'ScpMonitor - Shortcut.lnk', 
   'StarCraft II', 'Visual GBA', 'XAMPP Control Panel.lnk']
```

I have a bunch more shortcut files on the desktop such as Thunderbird, Blender, Unity3D, PaintShopPro, etc. They are not displayed when I run os.listdir(). I wish they were.

Any ideas as to why those shortcuts are not being displayed in the output?

Comment: An emulation connoisseur, I see... ;) fortunately I don't think SO cares. You should try right-clicking one of the shortcuts that isn't displayed and looking at the file location. See if it's really in that folder.

Comment: shouldn't the directory be `c:\\Users\\username\\Desktop`?

Comment: Are you sure that's the only directory where desktop contents are stored?

Comment: You guys are right, they actually are not in 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop' they are in 'C:\\Users\\Public\\PublicDesktop'
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You may post this as an answer as it solved the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files are actually not in `C:\Users\\Username\Desktop`, but in `C:\Users\Public\PublicDesktop`.